# How to protect ajax methods called via jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, codeigniter

I have a datagrid table in a user session (users visualizations by admin).

To initialize the datagrid I need to set the url data with an array with the items that should be in the table.

To do this, I must have an action allowed to show these data (Codeigniter mvc).

How can I protect my action to only allow access by users of my app via the jQuery.ajax() method?

For example, I'm already logged into my session and access a view with datagrid that uses this function to get the data and set it on a table:

```
  $('#content').WATable(
  {
    url: '/api/showusers'
  }).data('WATable');
```

Thank you!

Comment: What you are looking for is called CSRF protection.

Comment: Hmm.. this is activated in my forms but how can I prevent to not allowed users access this action with this data? using the crsf token?

Comment: Solution:


Make a REST API with digest autentication.

I used this REST server:
https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app/config/constants.php`

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Then in `showusers()`

```
public function showusers() {
    if(!IS_AJAX) { 
        show_404()
    }

    // continue with processing
}
```

I use this Everywhere!  If you're in a user-only area, codeigniter will handle the user authentication and make sure the action is being accessed only by ajax.